# Different fragment layout based on device android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, fragment

I am working on an android application that makes use of fragments. I used the standard template for fragments that is generated in the create-wizard. Now, I want to use a different 'ItemListFragment' layout for when 'mTwoPane' is true(screen sizes above 600dp). The layout on single pane devices will have a title and a 2x3 icon layout, while the mTwoPane devices won't have a title and will have a 1x6 layout, so all the icons will be under each other.

In my ItemListActivity.java, there is checked or the item_detail_container is present. If so, mTwoPane is set to true.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

        if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
            // The detail container view will be present only in the
            // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
            // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
            // activity should be in two-pane mode.
            mTwoPane = true;

            // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
            // 'activated' state when touched.
            ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
                    .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }


    }
```

My first thought was to check for mTwoPane in my ItemListFragment too, and pick the RootView based on this. But I couldn't get this to work. Here is what I did in my ItemListFragment:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view;
        boolean mTwoPane;
        if (getView().findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }
        else mTwoPane = false;

        if(!mTwoPane){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile_list, container, false);
        }
        else{
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablet_list, container, false);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

But this obviously wouldn't work, because the view needs to be instantiated before there could be checked or item_detail_container was present.

Then I started to think, should fragments be aware of the layout? Maybe I should have 2 list layouts, one for tablets and one for mobile. But then again,

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);
```

Has to be called first to check if mTwoPane is true.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android will pick the layout resource to use based on resource qualifiers, or buckets.

e.g.

layout-mdpi
layout-hdpi
layout-xlarge
layout-port
layout-sw600dp

These are all resource buckets, than can all contain a layout file named activity_item_list. Android will then pick the layout file to use based on the current devices attributes.

So the solution is to create a list_fragment layout file that exists in the layout folder, and the layout-sw600dp folder (or whatever you currently have). The layout in the layout-sw600dp folder can be adjusted for a tablet.

Have a read up on these articles for more info:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't think about using the layout folders for fragments. But it is obvious of course. Can't believe I didn't figure out myself!